# Requests to service get queued when client is a service in the same server

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, performance

I am having this weird issue. I have 3 WCF services on a server. Manager service is the main entry point for requests from the outside. another service is the logic of the application. the 3rd service is a DB connection service which both services go to and is doing most of the work (the DB does).

When I run a load test with requests to the manager and ran a performance test, I got 90 different threads running simultaneously, the 2nd service had about 50 and the DB connection had only about 12.

I feel this is a main performance problem in the application. when I profile both services I see they do wait a lot for responses from the DB service.

I tried running a test straight to the DB Service. I ran 80 threads and stopped them with a ManualEventHandler just after opening the channel and before sending the request. then when all were ready I've set the handler and it ran about 25 threads in the DB connection service.

So it is capable of working with more then 12 threads.

Any thoughts what is going on?

Why does the requests get queued?

Some additional information:

Binding is basichttpbinding but I tried net pipe ipc with same results.
Ive set context mode and concurrency to either per call or per session multiple with same results.

Also the services are self hosted.
The reason this is the architecture is like this is in order to allow multiple other services or applications to send requests straight to those services. In this particular event I test it as described, in other events flow may be different.

Comment: Have you made any kind of setup to your `ConcurrencyMode` settings? See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx. It has an impact on inter-service calls.

Comment: And why this design, if you don't mind me asking?. Seems to me like it's asking for trouble.

Comment: @thecoon why is this trouble? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means those requests are getting queued up on the way. If all your services are hosted on IIS you could use ASP.NET performance counters to see the number of pending request on each service level (WCF from my knowledge does not provides such performance counters).
As @the coon suggested this is wrong architectural approach for sure. Each service call can be considered an expensive one compared with having both business logic and data access operations performed by same service on different layers. To be honest I do not see the reason to use such an approach.

Comment: I am aware that the requests are queued, I am asking why do they get queued. I understand that it may seem wrong but how would you suggest doing it differently while still allowing other clients to send requests directly to the db connection service?

Comment: have you configured concurrency mode and throttling? If all services are WCF (and I assume they are) and you have access to all of them (and I assume you do) move the contracts from the DB service and business service in one service only. In this scenario you will have an entry point to the business service which will access the DAL directly ( and not by calling a separate service). Also if there are clients which have to access the DAL only, no issue there, since those DAL methods are exposed on same service using a different contract. What sort of binding are you using between services?

Comment: I've written in an edit of this question about binding and context. This suggestion about uniting the services sounds great thanks! But I am still puzzled by the behavior described, why do you think it happen? Maybe both services are competing on the same connection to the db service? If so why and Is there a way to overpass it?

Comment: I am not sure I get it, i thought that only one of your services is accessing the database. Even if both of them would try to access the database at same time should not cause this sort of issues, unless both are trying to access same resource in the database (same table) and one operation of one of those two services is locking it. Can you post the code of one service operation from each service?